# Spacing between React Grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, responsive-design

So I'm trying to build a react app page where I have on large or xl screen, the code will display all 9 boxes in one row. On a tablet screen, the layout will be split into two rows. On a phone screen, the layout will be split into three rows. I've gotten pretty far where all 9  boxes display in a row and are responsive however the spacing of them in the desktop version overlap and in the mobile version only one column appears when it should be a 3x3 grid. How can I change my current code to match this?

Here is what I have so far:

```
import { Box, Grid, Paper, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const Contained = styled(Box)({
  backgroundColor: "rgba(241, 243, 246, 1)",
  fontFamily: "Roboto",
  height: "100vh",
  width: "100vw",
});

const Appbox = styled("div")({
  backgroundColor: "#fff",
  border: "1px solid #E4E9F2",
  borderRadius: "4px",
  color: "#64768C",
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: "column",
  justifyContent: "center",
  alignItems: "center",
  padding: "16px",
  textAlign: "center",
  height: "92px",
  width: "133px",
  "&:hover": {
    boxShadow: "0px 3px 6px #00000029",
  },
});

const StatsNumber = styled(Typography)({
  fontSize: "32px",
  fontWeight: 600,
});

function ResponsiveGrid() {
  return (
    <Contained>
      <Typography
        align="left"
        variant="h1"
        sx={{ margin: "0px 32px 24px 32px", fontSize: "24px" }}
      >
        Dashboard
      </Typography>
      <Grid item xl = {18} xs={12}>
        <Paper sx={{ padding: "32px", height: "100%" }}>
          <Grid container spacing={2} sx={{flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
            <Grid item xl={2} lg={2} md={4} sm={6} xs={12}>
              <Appbox>
                <StatsNumber>33</StatsNumber>
                <Typography>Text Here</Typography>
              </Appbox>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xl={2} lg={2} md={4} sm={6} xs={12}>
              <Appbox>
                <StatsNumber>33</StatsNumber>
                <Typography>Text Here</Typography>
              </Appbox>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xl={2} lg={2} md={4} sm={6} xs={12}>
              <Appbox>
                <StatsNumber>33</StatsNumber>
                <Typography>Text Here</Typography>
              </Appbox>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xl={1} lg={2} md={4} sm={6} xs={12}>
              <Appbox>
                <StatsNumber>33</StatsNumber>
                <Typography>Text Here</Typography>
              </Appbox>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xl={1} lg={2} md={4} sm={6} xs={12}>
              <Appbox>
                <StatsNumber>33</StatsNumber>
                <Typography>Text Here</Typography>
              </Appbox>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xl={1} lg={2} md={4} sm={6} xs={12}>
              <Appbox>
                <StatsNumber>33</StatsNumber>
                <Typography>Text Here</Typography>
              </Appbox>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xl={1} lg={2} md={4} sm={6} xs={12}>
              <Appbox>
                <StatsNumber>33</StatsNumber>
                <Typography>Text Here</Typography>
              </Appbox>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xl={1} lg={2} md={4} sm={6} xs={12}>
              <Appbox>
                <StatsNumber>33</StatsNumber>
                <Typography>Text Here</Typography>
              </Appbox>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xl={1} lg={2} md={4} sm={6} xs={12}>
              <Appbox>
                <StatsNumber>33</StatsNumber>
                <Typography>Text Here</Typography>
              </Appbox>
            </Grid>
            </Grid>
            </Paper>
            </Grid>
            </Contained>
  )}

  export default ResponsiveGrid
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the new approach, I have used **map function** to create all columns instead of writing every one of them.

And added a new element **ResponsiveGridBox** which is styled using styled-components to make columns responsive for 3 screen sizes(mobile, tablet, desktop) and mapped the array inside this component.

Here is the updated [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-forest-8987sc?file=/src/Responsive.jsx)

I hope this is what you wanted to achieve, there are some style issues in small screen.

Comment: Here were the requirements: 
On large or xl screen, the code will display all 9 boxes in one row while being evenly spaced. On a tablet screen, the layout will be split into two rows. On a phone screen, the layout will be split into three rows and be like a 3x3 grid

Comment: The reason why I avoided using your method before was because everything got pushed to 2 lines on a larger laptop screen which didn't meet the requirement

Comment: I've updated the images so can you can see what it's supposed to look like

Comment: But suppose I had different texts in there such as "Application" and there was one that said "Status", sx={{ width: "max-content" }} causes a spacing issue

Comment: In that case try sx={{ width: "fit-content" }}

Comment: I tried that and some boxes seem bigger than others still, is there any way to keep them the same size while not messing up the grid?

Comment: Actually solution doesn't work if words are longer than others in the box. Please see updated sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/responsive-grid-forked-n4iisk?file=/src/Responsive.jsx